# If page called directly then throw 404

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a page on a WordPress site called AJAX which lives here: domain.com/ajax/ This page is used for AJAX calls. What I want to prevent is direct access to it, so basically allow JS to call the page but if someone types in the url and tries to access it on its own then they will get a 404 (basically making it as though the page doesn't exist)

The page has its own template file so can have a nice bit of PHP to detect this, but what would that code be? Thanks.

Comment: "What I want to prevent is direct access to it" - this begs the question "why, what do you want to achieve, what is your actual goal?". The question would be basically the same for any type of http request, regardless of whether "ajax" is used on the client-side.

Comment: Well in the same way a contact form may use a file or the comment system uses a comment.php file you want to allow a form to access it but dont want anyone loading it direct as its a useless on its own as it wont have any content like <head> and that just pure code relative to the call.

Comment: I thought you wanted it as a kind of authorization thingy ("only users 'on' my website are allowed to request that data - and only via xhr"). Now it sounds more like you want to "protect" (inexperienced) users from getting data in a format that is useless to them. Sorry for be nit-picking (I don't like it if someone is second-guessing my every thought too), but again: Why? If you want to restrict access use mechanisms like for every other http request, sessions for example. But don't patronize users by deciding what is useless without a very, very good reason.

Comment: I think you misunderstanding what I mean. The page is not a real page, it has no <html> no <head> and no <body> its just a simple <div> with some php query that my JS file talks to. But because I'm using WordPress and using a page I don't want users to access it directly as its pure crap basically and not a page.

Answer (score 2):

You can check header "X-Requested-With" for XmlHttpRequest, but this isn't 100% secure solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the Ajax file require a Get or Post variable. Redirect the user to other page if that variable is not passed.